# MongooseError[CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5f37f59e549a291510f1c0dd" at path "_id" for model "residence"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a project for accommodations, each accommodation has residences stored and cab be deleted. While trying to delete a residence I get the error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5f37f59e549a291510f1c0dd" at path "_id" for model "residence".

**Accommodation Schema**

````
    name: String,
    image: String, 
    address: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    description: String,
    residences: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "residence"
        }
    ]
}); ```

**Residence Schema**

```ResidencesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    NoOfStudents: Number,
    price: String,
    images: String,
    type: String
});  ```

***Delete Route***

``` app.delete("/accommodations/:id/residences/:resId", function(req, res){
    Residence.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.resId, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("back");
        }else{
            res.redirect("/accommodations/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});  ```
````

Comment: you need to convert string id to object id try this. `Residence.findByIdAndRemove(mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.resId),`

Comment: @turivishal I tried this but it returns the object(residence as null)